# Laravel mail queue and excel attachement causing JSON_ERROR_UTF8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel

Have a problem while trying to queue mail that have attachment.

I can send an email without any problems without queue. Attachment is correct and can be opened. Problem appear when I try to queue that email. Excel generated by maatwebsite/excel lib

Error:

```
InvalidPayloadException in Queue.php line 89:
 5
```

I found that this part of code throws this error:

```
...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Queue.php
protected function createPayload($job, $data = '', $queue = null)
{
    $payload = json_encode($this->createPayloadArray($job, $data, $queue));

    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new InvalidPayloadException;
    }

    return $payload;
}
```

My code looks like:

```
excel = Excel::create('Report', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
            $sheet->fromArray([['aaa']]);
        });
    })->string('xlsx');

    Mail::to('mail@mail.com')
        ->queue(new Report($excel));
```

I've tried to utf8_encode($excel) but then I cannot open mail attachment and I think that any operation on generated excel will corrupt file...

This problem also appear when I try to attach excel file from disk.

Any help?

Comment: PHPExcel objects can't be serialized - they should be treated as a resource in that regard; so you're better saving the data in some manner and using a reference to where you've saved it in the queue task

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes, thats true - PHPExcel objects can't be serialized. I resolved that issue like you wrote. Had to use $excel->store("xlsx", false, true)['full']; insted of $excel->string('xlsx'); As next just attach file to the mail as a regular file. Thanks.